# Need help fixing a malloc overwriting a variable

Tags: c, malloc, buffer-overflow

i'm a student and I'am required to write some function, however one of my function which is
"like" a strjoin is overwriting a buffer at some point and I don't understand why, there is no memory leaks so it should not be happening but I don't believe the error could be on the compilator part.

There is the code of my function:
`

```
char    *ft_strnjoin(char *s1, const char * const s2, size_t n)
{
    char    *new;
    size_t  s1len;
    size_t  s2len;

    if (!s2)
        return (NULL);
    s1len = ft_strlen(s1);
    s2len = ft_strlen(s2);
    if (!s2len)
        return (s1);
    if (s2len > n)
        s2len = n;
    new = malloc(s1len + s2len + 1);
    if (!new && !s1)
        return (NULL);
    else if (!new)
        return (free(s1), NULL);
    ft_memset(new, 0, s1len + s2len + 1);
    ft_memcpy(new, s1, s1len);
    ft_memcpy(new + s1len, s2, s2len);
    return (free(s1), new);
}
```

Ps: ft_strlen, fr_memcpy and ft_memset behare exactly the same as the standard one exept that they chekc for a NULL before, it is required as my ft_strnjoin can accept a NULL s1.

This is what gdb show me:
at ft_strnjoin(s1: 0X0, S2: 0X55...596d9 = '0', n: 42)
the line before `new = malloc(s1len + s2len + 1);` s2 is 0x55...596d9 which point to ['0', 0], s1len = 0 and s2len = 1
after this line, when the malloc have been executed, the same s2 is now 0x55...596d9 (address is the same) but now point to ['l', \371, \367, \377, \177].

I have absolutely no idea about what is happening...
RePs: s2 is on the stack

I tried debugging with gdb, which failed. I tried changing compilator the issue persisted, I tried upgrading my system package and using another computer.

Comment: Regarding e.g. `return (free(s1), new);` please don't do like that. It doesn't help with readability and maintainability of the code.

Comment: Regarding memory leaks, those happen when you allocate memory but don't free it. A buffer overrun is unrelated to memory (or other resource) leaks.

Comment: As for your problem, please try to create a [mre] and [edit] your question to show it. What you claim happens should not happen unless you have some *undefined behavior* or similar in the code you *don't* show us.

Comment: `free(s1)` seems like a poor choice to have `ft_strjoin` free the pointer it is passed.  Freeing s1 is not part of joining strings, and generally allocation and freeing would be delegated to the same code.

Comment: Using `ft_memset` to set all of the memory to a value, and then directly overwriting almost all of that memory seems like a waste. Just copy the strings, then set the single null-terminator character at the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use memcpy/memmove at all in this case:

```
char *ft_strnjoin(char *s1, const char * const s2, size_t n)
{
    char    *new;
    size_t  s1len = s1 ? strlen(s1) : 0;
    size_t  s2len = s2 ? strlen(s2) : 0;

    if((s1len + s2len) && n)
    {
        new = malloc(n = ((s1len + s2len) < n ? (s1len + s2len + 1) : n));
        if(new)
        {
            char *wrk = new;
            size_t i = 0;
            if(s1) while(--n && *s1) *wrk++ = *s1++;
            if(s2 && n) while(n-- && s2[i]) *wrk++ = s2[i++];
            *wrk = 0;
        }
    }
    return new;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "Hello ";
    char *s2 = "world";
    char *s3;

    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(s1,s2,8)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(s1,s2,1)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(s1,s2,0)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(s1,s2,14)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(s1,NULL,11)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(NULL,s2,11)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
    printf("`%s`\n", (s3 = ft_strnjoin(NULL,NULL,11)) ? s3 : "NULL");
    free(s3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank for the replies, the error was quite stupid and the code I posted was in fact irrelevant.

I was reallocating some memory at some point and in this case s2 was a pointer over a buffer that have been moved. So my buffer changed position, s2 was still pointing over the freed memory and malloc was allocating that piece of memory. That was why malloc was "changing" s2 contents...

I'll remember, if some buffer have the slightest change of being moved I must iterate over it using an index and not a pointer.

Thank you everyone !